# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to resolve Detected package version outside of dependency constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nuget-package

In my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, as I tried to install:

> Install-Package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection -Version 11.0.0

through the Nugget package, I got this error:

> Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Storage 5.2.0 requires AutoMapper (>= 10.0.0 && < 11.0.0) but version AutoMapper 11.0.1 was resolved.

While trying to resolve it, I install AutoMapper ver-11.0.1

Then the application flagged AutoMapper that was installed.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Install latest version of Automapper.

Comment: @KiranJoshi - That's what I did that brought the error. I mean latest automapper

Comment: Update (or add an explicit reference to) a version of the  `Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Storage` NuGet package that supports AutoMapper version 11+.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TLDR: Downgrade `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` to `8.1.1` that depends on `AutoMapper (>= 10.1.1 && < 11.0.0)`

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/8.1.1

Long answer:

I got a similar warning or error as well but for me it was when installing NuGet `AutoMapper`:

> NU1608 Detected package version outside of dependency constraint:
> Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Storage 5.2.0 requires
> AutoMapper (>= 10.0.0 && < 11.0.0) but version AutoMapper 11.0.1 was
> resolved.

You probably have the NuGet `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer` or similar installed.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer

If you look at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer NuGet dependencies you will see:

- net6.0
- Duende.IdentityServer (>= 5.2.0)
- Duende.IdentityServer.AspNetIdentity (>= 5.2.0)
- Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework (>= 5.2.0)
- Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Storage (>= 5.2.0)
- Duende.IdentityServer.Storage (>= 5.2.0)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer (>= 6.0.5)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 6.0.5)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI (>= 6.0.5)
- Microsoft.Extensions.Http (>= 6.0.0)
- Newtonsoft.Json (>= 13.0.1)

You could solve it by manually updating libraries below:

- Duende.IdentityServer
- Duende.IdentityServer.AspNetIdentity
- Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework
- Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Storage
- Duende.IdentityServer.Storage

Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Storage 6.1.0 has the following dependencies which will fix your error:

- net6.0
- AutoMapper (>= 11.0.0 && < 12.0.0)
- Duende.IdentityServer.Storage (>= 6.1.0)
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (>= 6.0.0)

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Storage/

However this will probably give you this exception when running your code for `endpoints.MapRazorPages();`.

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or
> more of the requested types. Method 'get_ServerSideSessions' in type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ApiAuthorizationDbContext`1'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer,
> Version=6.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
> does not have an implementation.'

I have asked Microsoft to update `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer` so it is compatible with  latest `Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Storage` which would fix the problem.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41897